# Cyclic Noncommutative Multiplication

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I work with traces of long matrix products and I want mathematica to employ the cyclicity when simplifying.

I use this redefinition of the non-commutative multiplication:

```
Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply];
Clear[NonCommutativeMultiply]

(*Factor out numerics-- could generalize to some ScalarQ*)
nc : NonCommutativeMultiply[a__] /; MemberQ[{a}, _?NumericQ] := 
 NCMFactorNumericQ[NCM[a]] /. NCM -> NonCommutativeMultiply

(*Simplify Powers*)    
b___ ** a_^n_. ** a_^m_. ** c___ := 
 NCM[b, a^(n + m), c] /. NCM -> NonCommutativeMultiply

(*Minus*)
NonCommutativeMultiply[a___, b_Times, c___] := 
 NCMFactorNumericQ[NCM[a, Sequence @@ b, c]] /. 
  NCM -> NonCommutativeMultiply
Protect[NonCommutativeMultiply];

Unprotect[NCM];
Clear[NCM]
NCMFactorNumericQ[nc_NCM] := 
 With[{pos = Position[nc, _?NumericQ, 1]}, 
  Times @@ Extract[nc, pos] Delete[nc, pos]]
NCM[a_] := a
NCM[] := 1
Protect[NCM];
```

which was given as an answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023863/redefine-noncommutative-multiplication-in-mathematica) and is very helpful, but I want it to be able to cancel `A**B**C` with `-B**C**A` (but only if these matrices stand alone, i.e. I don't want it to cancel `A**B**C**D` with `-B**C**A**D`).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Beware! By default, `**` is associative, but one implication of the last statement is that your multiplication is not. Thus, even an expression like `A**B**C` is not well-defined, because it could mean either `(A**B)**C` or `A**(B**C)`. You probably should not be thinking of your manipulations with traces as resulting from a binary operation at all.

Comment: Good point, @whuber .
I was thinking something along the lines of letting it check if what is left and right is a one (then it can cycle) or something else (then it can't).
On the other hand, I don't really need it to be encoded in the multiplication itself. I'd be perfectly happy with a newly defined trace that I can apply on my expressions and that knows that cyclic permutations are identical.

Answer (score 1):

[NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) supports a trace type operator. It will automatically reduce

```
tr[a ** b ** c - b ** c ** a]
```

to

> 0

and

```
tr[a ** b ** c ** d - b ** c ** a ** d]
```

> tr[a ** b ** c ** d] - tr[a ** d ** b ** c]

It achieves that by automatically canonizing the sorting of the arguments or `tr`.

P.S.: We are in the process of updating NCAlgebra so you might want to try our latest beta version from [here](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/tree/v6.0.0), which you can install as a paclet.